# Load Jquery Accordion after button click using Jquery

Tags: accordion, jquery-ui-accordion

I am using JQuery UI Accordion, it works fine with the static content. However when i am loading the H3 and Div tags of the accordion from the ajax rest service call. The data is coming up properly but accordion is not loading up

```
onSuccess: function (data) {
        var results = data.d.query.PrimaryQueryResult.RelevantResults.Table.Rows.results;
        var html = "";

        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
            html += "<div><h3><a href=\"#\">";
            html += results[i].Cells.results[3].Value;
            html += "</a></h3><p>"
            html += results[i].Cells.results[6].Value;
            html += "</p></div>";
        }
$("#results_accordion").accordion();
```

My Accordion Div is empty initially whihc i want to fill up with the data from the above service call on button click.

```
$("#results_accordion").accordion();
```

Any help ?

Comment: Just to add here is the flow..
First Page loads with empty results_accordion div --> User click on button --> AJAX call brings the data to be loaded on the Accordion using JQuery

Comment: you should first add the html content to your page before you execute the accordion function

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#results_accordion").html(html).accordion();
```

you should first add the html content to your page before you execute the accordion function

Answer (score 0):

This is my actual click event which is called..

```
function onclic(queryTerms) {

Results = {
    element: '',
    url: '',

    init: function (element) {
        Results.element = element;
        Results.url = someurl;
    },

    load: function () {
        $.support.cors = true;
        $.ajax(
                {
                    url: Results.url,
                    method: "GET",
                    headers: {
                        "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                    },
                    success: Results.onSuccess,
                    error: Results.onError
                }
            );
    },

    onSuccess: function (data) {
        var results = data.d.results;
        var html = "";

        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
            html += "<div><h3><a href=\"#\">";
            html += results[i].Cells.results[3].Value;
            html += "</a></h3><p>"
            html += results[i].Cells.results[6].Value;
            html += "</p></div>";
        }


        Results.element.html(html);
        $("#results_accordion").accordion();
    },

    onError: function (err) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(err));
    }
}

Results.init($('#results_accordion'));
Results.load();
$("#results_accordion").accordion();
```

}

Comment: As you can see i have called $("#results_accordion").accordion(); after Results.load() is called.